# How do I find a similar RNN as a starting point?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, tensorflow, long-short-term-memory, time-series

I am new to machine learning and neural networks and I want to create a neural network for a study project.

I would like to create a RNN, that uses one (A) or several time series (with the same length, A, B, C...) as an input and creates another time series (Z) as an output from that. Basically all time series are derived from on time series, so their relationship that can be expressed mathematically. ex. B = dA/dt, ... C = moving mean(B)

For training I want to feed the NN with the input and output time series, which I can create with a simulation with known parameters, so that I know the output is correct.

I am new to working with neural networks and couldn't find a NN that seemed to do a similar job. Does somebody have a NN in mind that could do the job?

I asked chatGPT, which said that simple RNNs with or without LSTM or GRU cells could do the job.

Any ideas?

Comment: From the information you have given, then yes any basic RNN architecture could do the job. Some might work better than others in practice, depending on your data. You don't really give enough detail to say much more though, and it is not clear what you are expecting when you ask someone to recommend an NN.

Comment: Well my professor just said I should ask in a forum to find a similar network. The problem is I don't know what I am looking for exactly. I found something here but I am not sure if it is what I am looking for and if it is usable for the task I am doing. https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/ Should I go for that?

Comment: For training I will have variable input time series let's say 5, which are all derived from one series. And when I use the NN then I only give 4 time series and it predicts the 5th time series. I am just looking for a NN that does something like this to read upon.

Comment: Yes your linked example looks fine to me, and from your description so far it seems like it would work. I suggest you look into it to the level where you could follow the description and make the example, and then take that to your professor.